# How query avoid locking on table write continuously in a transaction takes a few times?

Tags: sql-server

I have a business job which writes into a table every 1 minute. I also have a client query result from the job. Sometimes query slow when does in job time. How query avoid locking on table write continuously in a transaction takes a few times?

Comment: Consider using the `SNAPSHOT` isolation  level in the query so that it is not blocked by the job's uncommitted transactions.

Comment: But I will have dirty data in snapshot isolation level.

Comment: No,   `SNAPSHOT` does not allow dirty reads. Only transactionally consistent data are returned. Perhaps you're thinking of `READ_UNCOMMITTED`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the [`SNAPSHOT` isolation level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server) for the `SELECT` queries. The `SNAPSHOT` isolation level uses row versioning instead of locking to provide consistent results and avoid `SELECT` queries  from  being blocked by the concurrent job and prevent the job from being blocked by those `SELECT` queries.

Note that you can use the `SNAPSHOT` isolation level with or without explict transactions. In the later case, it provides statement level read consistency using row versioning similarly to the `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` database option but allows targeted use rather than a database wide setting that affects all database queries.